# OMNet++: EtherSwitch and EtherHost device configurations and routing. How to?

Tags: routes, omnet++

i am trying to build a network simulation with OMNet++. Problem is i dont know how to configure EtherSwitch and EtherHost devices and give them IP. What is the necessary routing code to rout traffic between switches and routers. IP addresses of the routers's ports must be like table below;

Router Leg IP
1 ------ 1 --- 192.168.1.0/24
1 ------ 4 --- 192.168.4.1
1 ------ 5 --- 192.168.5.1
2 ------ 2 --- 192.168.2.0/24
2 ------ 5 --- 192.168.5.2
2 ------ 6 --- 192.168.6.2
3 ------ 3 --- 192.168.3.0/24
3 ------ 4 --- 192.168.4.3
3 ------ 6 --- 192.168.6.3

Here image of the required network:

[image: Network]

My NED file:

```
import inet.nodes.inet.Router;
import inet.nodes.inet.StandardHost;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.nodes.ethernet.EtherSwitch;
import inet.nodes.ethernet.EtherHost;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.FlatNetworkConfigurator;

network gyte
{
    @display("bgb=457,318");
    types:
    channel geth extends DatarateChannel
    {
        datarate = 1Gbps;
    }

    channel hgeth extends DatarateChannel
    {
        datarate = 512Mbps;
    }

    submodules:
    // Routers
    routers[3]: Router {
        parameters:
            @display("p=208,272,row=id;i=abstract/router");

        gates:
            pppg[3];
    }

    // Switches
    switches[3]: EtherSwitch {
        parameters:
            @display("p=179,162,row");

        gates:
            ethg[3];
    }

    // Hosts
    ehosts[4]: EtherHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=384,56,row");

        gates:
            ethg;
    }

    // Servers
    eservers[2]: EtherHost {
        parameters:
            @display("i=device/server;p=117,71,row");

        gates:
            ethg;
    }

    configurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator {

        @display("p=22,25");
    }

connections:
    ehosts[0].ethg <--> switchs[0].ethg[0];
    eservers[0].ethg <--> switchs[0].ethg[1];

    ehosts[1].ethg <--> switchs[1].ethg[0];
    eservers[1].ethg <--> switchs[1].ethg[1];

    switchs[0].ethg[2] <--> routers[0].pppg[0];
    switchs[1].ethg[2] <--> routers[1].pppg[0];

    routers[0].pppg[1] <--> routers[1].pppg[1];
    routers[0].pppg[2] <--> routers[2].pppg[0];
    routers[1].pppg[2] <--> routers[2].pppg[1];
    routers[2].pppg[2] <--> switchs[2].ethg[0];

    switchs[2].ethg[1] <--> ehosts[2].ethg;
    switchs[2].ethg[2] <--> ehosts[3].ethg;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches dont have an IP address (In reality they have in order to administrate the Switch). Switching (Layer 2) is based on MAC addresses.
So in the simulation you dont have to configure anything for the Switches.

In order to assign IP addresses to the hosts and routers and add the routes to the routing tables you can use the "flatnetworkconfigurator" module. Simply put it in your NED file.
But all IP addresses will be out of one subnet.

Other solution is to use MRT files. There you specify with linux syntax the IP, subnetmask, gateway etc. for each interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the real problem is how can i route a package to a host which is connected to a swich. In this case, routing from router1 to istemci1(host1). How the irt or mrt files should be like?

Comment: Why are you not simply use the flatnetworkConfigurator? It will add the routes to the routers automatically. The switch is not seen by the router. It only has to know which subnet is connected to which interface, e.g: destination subnet 192.168.1.0/24 is connected to interface 1 . Again, it does not matter if there is a Switch!

Comment: Thanks again. It is homework :) So i cant use flatnetworkConfigurator. By the way i have managed to setup the network but i am still confused. How can i sen messages from every host.

Comment: you can use the ping app in the standardHost or you can use one of the UDPApps. There are examples how to configure the INI file in the right way.